# How to print html list elements side by side while iteration

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do noticeboard so I have used one which is correct as my expectation in horizontal when the list elements predefined. But I am trying add data dynamically then the sticky notes printed vertically.

This is  fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/z6u81mp4/

**See I have used id nb for the ul  so I need css according that**

**why margin right is not working style="margin-right: 500px;"**

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <h2>Title #1</h2>
        <p>Text Content #1</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <h2>Title #2</h2>
        <p>Text Content #2</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <h2>Title #3</h2>
        <p>Text Content #3</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <h2>Title #4</h2>
        <p>Text Content #4</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <h2>Title #5</h2>
        <p>Text Content #5</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <h2>Title #6</h2>
        <p>Text Content #6</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <h2>Title #2</h2>
        <p>Text Content #2</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <h2>Title #7</h2>
        <p>Text Content #7</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <h2>Title #8</h2>
        <p>Text Content #8</p>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
 #nb>li{
  list-style:none;
}
#nb{
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:3em;
    display: flex;
}
#nb>li>a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#000;
  background:#ffc;
  display:block;
 /*  height:10em; */
 /*  width:10em; */
  padding:1em;
  -moz-box-shadow:5px 5px 7px rgba(33,33,33,1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px rgba(33,33,33,.7);
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px rgba(33,33,33,.7);
  -moz-transition:-moz-transform .15s linear;
  -o-transition:-o-transform .15s linear;
  -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform .15s linear;
}
#nb>li{
  margin:1em;
  float:left;
  display: flex;
}
#nb>li>h2{
  font-size:140%;
  font-weight:bold;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}
#nb>li>p{
  font-family:"Reenie Beanie",arial,sans-serif;
  font-size:180%;
}
#nb>li>a{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-6deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-6deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(-6deg);
}
#nb>li:nth-child(even)>a{
  -o-transform:rotate(4deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(4deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(4deg);
  position:relative;
  top:5px;
  background:#cfc;
}
#nb>li:nth-child(3n)>a{
  -o-transform:rotate(-3deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(-3deg);
  position:relative;
  top:-5px;
  background:#ccf;
}
#nb>li:nth-child(5n)>a{
  -o-transform:rotate(5deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(5deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(5deg);
  position:relative;
  top:-10px;
}
#nb>li>a:hover,#nb>li>a:focus{
  box-shadow:10px 10px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  -moz-box-shadow:10px 10px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.25);
  -o-transform: scale(1.25);
  position:relative;
  z-index:5;
}
```

**code used in iteration**

```
<s:iterator value="noticeboardRecords" status="rowStatus">
                                            <ul id="nb">        
                                        <s:if test="#rowStatus.index == 0">

                                            <li style="width:200px;">
                                            <a href="#">                                                
                                                    <h5><s:date name="noticeDate" format="dd/MMM/yyyy" /></h5>
                                                    <h5><b><s:property value="noticeType" /></b></h5>
                                                    <p><s:property value="noticeMessage" /></p>
                                            </a>                                            
                                            </li>                                           

                                        </s:if>     

                                        <s:if test="#rowStatus.index == 1">

                                            <li style="margin-right: 500px;">
                                            <a href="#">                                                
                                                    <h5><s:date name="noticeDate" format="dd/MMM/yyyy" /></h5>
                                                    <h5><b><s:property value="noticeType" /></b></h5>
                                                    <p><s:property value="noticeMessage" /></p>
                                            </a>                                            
                                            </li>               


                                        </s:if> 


                                        <s:if test="#rowStatus.index == 2">

                                            <li>
                                            <a href="#">                                                
                                                    <h5><s:date name="noticeDate" format="dd/MMM/yyyy" /></h5>
                                                    <h5><b><s:property value="noticeType" /></b></h5>
                                                    <p><s:property value="noticeMessage" /></p>
                                            </a>                                            
                                            </li>               


                                        </s:if> 


                                        <s:if test="#rowStatus.index == 3">

                                            <li>
                                            <a href="#">                                                
                                                    <h5><s:date name="noticeDate" format="dd/MMM/yyyy" /></h5>
                                                    <h5><b><s:property value="noticeType" /></b></h5>
                                                    <p><s:property value="noticeMessage" /></p>
                                            </a>                                            
                                            </li>               


                                        </s:if> 

                                        <s:if test="#rowStatus.index ==4">

                                            <li>
                                            <a href="#">                                                
                                                    <h5><s:date name="noticeDate" format="dd/MMM/yyyy" /></h5>
                                                    <h5><b><s:property value="noticeType" /></b></h5>
                                                    <p><s:property value="noticeMessage" /></p>
                                            </a>                                            
                                            </li>           

                                        </s:if> 


                                            </ul>                                   
                                    </s:iterator>
```

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear. Your layout is flexible, with enough width your sticky notes line up side by side; do you not want this and instead only want them to align vertically?

Comment: I want horizontal align

Comment: With enough viewport width they do line up horizontally. If you want them to all line up horizontally, and you always know how many of them there will be, you can set each to part of the 100% width. Eg. four sticky notes would take up 25% each of the width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this question i should use iterator inside ul and make first li as constant(with no inline style) then for  rest lists given inline style

```
<ul id="nb">
    <s:iterator value="noticeboardRecords" status="rowStatus">

    <s:if test="#rowStatus.index==0">
    <li style="width:250px;">
     <a href="#">
     <h5><s:date name="noticeDate" format="dd/MMM/yyyy" /></h5>
     <h5><b><s:property value="noticeType" /></b></h5>
     <p><s:property value="noticeMessage" /></p>
    </a>
    </li>    
    </s:if>

    <s:if test="#rowStatus.index==1">
    <li style="margin-left: 100px;">
     <a href="#" style="background: #ffc">
     <h5><s:date name="noticeDate" format="dd/MMM/yyyy" /></h5>
     <h5><b><s:property value="noticeType" /></b></h5>
     <p><s:property value="noticeMessage" /></p>
    </a>
    </li>
    </s:if>




     <s:if test="#rowStatus.index==2">
     <li  style="margin-top: 100px;margin-left: 100px">
     <a href="#" style="background: #ffc">
     <h5><s:date name="noticeDate" format="dd/MMM/yyyy" /></h5>
     <h5><b><s:property value="noticeType" /></b></h5>
     <p><s:property value="noticeMessage" /></p>
    </a>
    </li>
      </s:if>



     <s:if test="#rowStatus.index==3">
    <li   style="margin-top:50px;margin-left: 100px;">
     <a href="#" style="background: #ffc">
     <h5><s:date name="noticeDate" format="dd/MMM/yyyy" /></h5>
     <h5><b><s:property value="noticeType" /></b></h5>
     <p><s:property value="noticeMessage" /></p>
    </a>
    </li>
      </s:if>



     <s:if test="#rowStatus.index==4">
     <li  style="margin-top:50px;margin-right: 500px;width:250px;">
     <a href="#">
     <h5><s:date name="noticeDate" format="dd/MMM/yyyy" /></h5>
     <h5><b><s:property value="noticeType" /></b></h5>
     <p><s:property value="noticeMessage" /></p>
    </a>
    </li>
      </s:if>
     </s:iterator>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want horizontaly align then you can just simply use `flex`.
Which add `display: flex`  to `ul`.

Something like below

```css
 #nb>li{
  list-style:none;
}
#nb{
  padding:3em;
  display: flex;
}
#nb>li>a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#000;
  background:#ffc;
  display:block;
 /*  height:10em; */
 /*  width:10em; */
  padding:1em;
  -moz-box-shadow:5px 5px 7px rgba(33,33,33,1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px rgba(33,33,33,.7);
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px rgba(33,33,33,.7);
  -moz-transition:-moz-transform .15s linear;
  -o-transition:-o-transform .15s linear;
  -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform .15s linear;
}
#nb>li{
  margin:1em;
  float:left;
  display: flex;
}
#nb>li>h2{
  font-size:140%;
  font-weight:bold;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}
#nb>li>p{
  font-family:"Reenie Beanie",arial,sans-serif;
  font-size:180%;
}
#nb>li>a{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-6deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-6deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(-6deg);
}
#nb>li:nth-child(even)>a{
  -o-transform:rotate(4deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(4deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(4deg);
  position:relative;
  top:5px;
  background:#cfc;
}
#nb>li:nth-child(3n)>a{
  -o-transform:rotate(-3deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(-3deg);
  position:relative;
  top:-5px;
  background:#ccf;
}
#nb>li:nth-child(5n)>a{
  -o-transform:rotate(5deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(5deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(5deg);
  position:relative;
  top:-10px;
}
#nb>li>a:hover,#nb>li>a:focus{
  box-shadow:10px 10px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  -moz-box-shadow:10px 10px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.25);
  -o-transform: scale(1.25);
  position:relative;
  z-index:5;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nb">
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <h2>Title #1</h2>
        <p>Text Content #1</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <h2>Title #2</h2>
        <p>Text Content #2</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <h2>Title #3</h2>
        <p>Text Content #3</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <h2>Title #4</h2>
        <p>Text Content #4</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <h2>Title #5</h2>
        <p>Text Content #5</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <h2>Title #6</h2>
        <p>Text Content #6</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <h2>Title #2</h2>
        <p>Text Content #2</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <h2>Title #7</h2>
        <p>Text Content #7</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <h2>Title #8</h2>
        <p>Text Content #8</p>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

#### output

[image]

> Note: if you dont want to `wrap` them simply remove `flex-wrap: wrap` from `ul`.

Hope this will help you in some way(y).

Comment: see i have used id nb for the ul please ul i need css according that

Comment: @jancypradeep see `update` section. see output screenshot (not sure if that what you want).

Comment: what ever you given output is absolutely fine but  i want css for second code i have posted code in iteration according that

Comment: why its happening iteration takes new row